# help parsing xml string in perl

Tags: perl

I'm having trouble doing a match for this xml string in perl.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><HttpRemoteException path="/proj/feed/abc" class="java.io.FileNotFoundException" message="/proj/feed/abc: No such file or directory."/>
```

I want to place a condition on `FileNotFoundException` like so:

code snippet:

```
my @lines = qx(@cmdargs);
foreach my $line (@lines) { print "$line"; }

if (my $line =~ m/(FileNotFoundException)/) {
     print "We have an ERROR: $line\n";
}
```

Error:

```
Use of uninitialized value in pattern match (m//) at ./tst.pl
```

Comment: Have you tried removing the "my"? It might be re-initializing your variable.

Comment: I did. I edited my question. I tried removing `my` as well and using `use strict` and `use warnings`

Comment: The following executes properly for me: `use strict;
use warnings;
my $line = '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><HttpRemoteException path="/proj/feed/abc" class="java.io.FileNotFoundException" message="/proj/feed/abc: No such file or directory."/>';

if ($line =~ m/(FileNotFoundException)/) {
   print "We have an ERROR: $line\n";
}`

Comment: thanks, works for me too. something else i need to troubleshoot then.

Comment: *Yawn.* Use an XML library to parse XML.  Use an XML library to parse XML. Use an XML library to parse XML. Use an XML library to parse XML. Use an XML library to parse XML. Use an XML library to parse XML. There are several for Perl, I always use `XML::LibXML`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should test `$line`inside the foreach loop:

```
my @lines = qx(@cmdargs);
foreach my $line (@lines) {
    print "$line";
    if ($line =~ m/(FileNotFoundException)/) {
        print "We have an ERROR: $line\n";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 5):

You never assign anything to the variable against which you match (since you create the variable right there inside the `if` condition), so it doesn't contain what you say it does.

Use `use strict; use warnings;`!!!

It would have given you a warning. Remove the `my`.